# Basic auth using token using Alamofire and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to log me into a website which use a basic form auth method.

Here is the **form** :

```
<form id="login-form" class="body" action="login" method="post">

                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="username">Identifiant</label>
                                        <input id="username" type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required="">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="password">Mot de passe</label>
                                        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required="">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="footer">
                                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                                            <input type="hidden" id="csrf_token" name="_csrf" value="6e35c328-a6e5-47ce-886e-16d0d1e71bd7">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
                                                Connexion
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

Here is my **code** :

```
  func login(user: String, password: String, token: String) {

        let parameters = [ "username" : user, "password" : password, "_csrf" : token]
        var headers = ["X-XSRF-TOKEN" : token, "Content-Type": "application/json"]

        if let authorizationHeader = Request.authorizationHeader(user: user, password: password) {
            headers[authorizationHeader.key] = authorizationHeader.value
        }

        let url = "https://auth.exemple.fr/login"

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
            .responseJSON { (response) in

                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    print(response.description)
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
        }

    }
```

As you can see, the website api is using a CSRF token which I retrieve thanks to another request. I'm then supposed to log the user with this token in headers/parameters. However I get this response from the server:

```
SUCCESS: {
    error = "Internal Server Error";
    message = "No message available";
    path = "/uaa/login";
    status = 500;
    timestamp = 1518704475137;
}
```

I already did that a long time ago and lost my code for reasons. Any idea? Thanks in advance for your help guys.

Comment: The server error 500 could be caused by any number of things. You need to look at your server to find out what's wrong. Can you debug on the server side? Logs?

Comment: No I can't. However the server works very well and I can log me easily from a browser.

Comment: Got it. Well, the server usually would tell you what's wrong with your request. If you can't see logs or get more detail than a 500 error code, it may be tough to debug. I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code.

Comment: Ok I made some changes in my code, now I have another response: `"Forbidden","message":"Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found."`

Comment: That seems pretty self-explanatory. But as I look at your code again, I suspect you need to post the user and password as form fields with Content-Type set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: IDs are not passed throw the URL.

Comment: Correct, if they were passed on the URL that would be a GET request. I'm suggesting you need to POST the parameters with Content-Type set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. There are many examples on how to do this if you search for them.